# Php detect file name load from url

Tags: php, url, self

**I want to detect the name of a file when loading my url, for example this:**

```
http://www.test.com/image/read_my_file.php
```

I want to know the name of the file loaded using PHP, in this case it´s `read_my_fyle.php`

**I tried with $PHP_SELF but the result is:**

```
image/read_my_file.php
```

And I want to get only the file name of PHP in the url which is loaded.

**Thank you, regards**

Comment: If you want to check the path of **any URL**, you need `parse_url()`.

Comment: If you mean `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, note that this can be abused by a malicious user, so use it carefully or not at all.

Comment: I use for no load one part of website in the header if the file no it´s the index.php

Comment: @user2202136 Use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` instead then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: `basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`

check this link for more info: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Comment: Yes yes , perfect now i do that now : <?php
$_POST['file']=$PHP_SELF;
echo basename($_POST['file']);
?>

Comment: Yes right all right i put positive when the system let me , thank´s :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this : `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`

Comment: In spite of its misleading name, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` does include the file's path, so it can't be used directly to detect the current file name. Parsing of the path will still be required.